# Advantage of OpenID connect over SAML

Tags: saml, openid-connect

I know that both the federation protocols can be used to manage user identities. 
Basically for Gmail based login, I want to know the benefits of using OpenID Connect over SAML.

OpenID connect is simpler JSON/REST based with compared to SAML. Apart from this is there any benefit of using OpenID Connect for Gmail based authentication?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you call "GMail based login".

1- if you mean *let my users read their mails on GMail using their credentials maintained in my internal organization*, OIDC and SAML will do the same. This is simply not the same protocol. So, depending on your internal directory (Active Directory, NetIQ eDirectory, openldap, /etc/passwd, etc.), it may be easier to use one of these protocols.

2- but if you mean *connect to GMail with my application, on behalf of my users*, only OIDC will let you do that, because of the underlying OAuth2.0 mechanism.

**OIDC means authentication and authorization, SAML only means authentication.**

Comment: Thanks for that explanation. Perhaps all that i want to do is avoid authenticating users at my end, instead delegate this authentication process to Gmail. So i guess like you said only OIDC can do this. Is it correct?

Comment: No, you only need authentication in this case. So this can be done with OIDC and SAML. For instance, with SAML, Google explains how-to do it here: https://support.google.com/a/answer/6087519?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

Historically, SAML and WS-Fed were used for enterprise connections and are browser based.

OIDC is for mobile and can be used via ADAL for native devices i.e. non-browser based e.g. dektop applications.